# How to change the default sleep time (5s) of resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I'm using Rails with resque.

The "sleep time" is the seconds of a worker sleeping after it can't find any new tasks.

The worker is created by `QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work`, and the default value is 5s, I can't to change it to 2s.

I have searched for this problem for several hours, somebody can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the INTERVAL environment variable.

```
INTERVAL=2 rake resque:work
```

Or whatever other parameters you'd like to tack on.

Comment: In my case I was able to use INTERVAL=0.1 so just whatever sleep method uses properly as an argument